# Split dt column values for accepting only month and year in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures, datatable

I have a DataTable column which has values like `01-04-2023 00:00:00`. I want only `04-2023` from that column and update in new DataTable. How can I split that in `DataTable`?

`Dt` has that column with  name `DATA_WITH_MONTH_YEAR`.

**update**

Below is the image of datatable columns

[image]

Below is the query:

```html
INSERT INTO TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST (
    POLITICAL_STATE_NAME,
    POLITICAL_STATE_CODE,
    RFCDATE,
    RFS_DATE,
    RFE1_DATE, 
    SITE_DROP_DATE,
    IP_COLO_SITEID,
    MW_INSTALLED,
    DG_NONDG,
    EB_NONEB,                                        
    ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
    ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE,
    RRH_COUNTCHANGE,
    RRH_CHANGEDDATE,
    TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE,
    TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE,                                        
    SAP_ID,
    CREATED_BY,
    RFS_DATE_5G,
    DROP_DATE_5G,
    OLT_COUNT,
    OLT_CHANGE_DATE,
    DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MINUTES,
    OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MINUTES,
    DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MIN_MY,
    OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MIN_MY) 

VALUES 
    (:POLITICAL_STATE_NAME,
    :POLITICAL_STATE_CODE,
    :RFCDATE,
    :RFS_DATE,
    :RFE1_DATE,
    :SITE_DROP_DATE,
    :IP_COLO_SITEID,
    :MW_INSTALLED,
    :DG_NONDG,
    :EB_NONEB,
    :ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
    :ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE,
    :RRH_COUNTCHANGE,
    :RRH_CHANGEDDATE,
    :TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE,
    :TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE,                                        
    :SAP_ID,
    :CREATED_BY,
    :RFS_DATE_5G,
    :DROP_DATE_5G,
    :OLT_COUNT,
    :OLT_CHANGE_DATE,
    :DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MINUTES,
    :OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MINUTES,
    :TO_CHAR(DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MINUTES_MON_YEAR, 'MM:YYYY') AS DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MINUTES_MON_YEAR,
    :OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MINUTES_MON_YEAR
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With properly storead date or timestamp datatypes, you can't separate date and time in Oracle. The `date` and `timestamp` datatypes will always have both components. Use the `to_char` command to control the format used to display that data when you select it.

```
select 
    to_char(my_date_column, 'MM-YYYY') "MyDateColumn" 
from my_table;
```

With - as in your case - date data improperly stored as text, you must convert it first to a date before you can convert it back to text in the desired format:

```
select 
    to_char(
        to_date(my_date_column,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    , 'MM-YYYY') "MyDateColumn" 
from my_table;
```

Note that any variation in the format of the "date" in its text column would blow up your query, as the input will not match the format filter in the `to_date` function call. My advice - if you have the opportunity - would be to make these proper date or timestamp columns and store the data correctly in the first place. Sooner or later, storing dates as strings without input validation will result in data corruption and you will have to do it anyway.

Comment: I am getting error as `ORA-01722: invalid number` with below query `select to_char(DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MIN_MY, 'MM-YYYY') AS DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MIN_MY,
       to_char(OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MIN_MY, 'MM-YYYY') AS OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MIN_MY
from tbl_ipcolo_billing_mst;`

Comment: What datatype are the columns? Sounds like they are maybe dates stored as text rather than proper dates...

Comment: datatype for that columns are `NVARCHAR2`

Comment: getting error as `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected` And I am using like this `to_char(
        to_date(DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MIN_MY,'MM-YYYY')
    , 'MM-YYYY') AS DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MINUTES_MON_YEAR` As I want only Month and year part from it

Comment: The `to_date` format must match the data in your column, which is `MM-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS`. Only apply your final formal of `MM-YYYY` to the final output of `to_char`.

Comment: yes now its working